# How can i handle JSESSIONID in Nginx conf

Tags: nginx, glassfish, mod-jk

Im using Nginx as FrontEnd Server, and behind it a Apache Http Server and begind it a Glassfish Application Server :) My problem is, when i need a static context like;

```
"http://127.0.0.1:8077/directory-web/resources/defaultTheme/images/facebook.png;jsessionid=07ab5b915530738297010cbc0b5c.worker1"
```

when i request to "http://127.0.0.1:8077/directory-web/resources/defaultTheme/images/facebook.png" link, image returns me, but nginx doesnt know what is JSESSIONID.

In production, Glassfish will be in two cluster. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "nginx doesnt know what is JSESSIONID"?  What problem are you having - what does nginx need to do with the JSESSIONID?

Comment: Path to facebook.png is ; http://127.0.0.1:8077/directory-web/resources/defaultTheme/images/facebook.png (this ok), but do you know a path like this ....eme/images/facebook.png;JKDFBJDBVD ?? 404 STATUS CODE TURNS me by Nginx, coz its not a path only a cookie

Comment: It shouldn't care what path it's proxying - how is your nginx configured?

Comment: http://chopapp.com/#5pwm5dcf

Comment: in html directory static files stands. but, facebook.png;jsessionid=07ab5b915530738297010cbc0b5c.worker1" is not a file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location ~* ^(.+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|css|png|js|ico))(?:;.+)?$ {
    try_files $1 =404;
    access_log off;
    expires max;
}
```

Comment: you except all static resource, but i need only except ;jsessionidblablabla

Comment: `location ~* ^(.+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|css|png|js|ico));jsessionid= {`

Comment: but, it must accept jpeg,gif,css,png,js and ico for example : xx.png and xx.js?fgdfgjd but it shouldnt accept xx.png;jsessionbdljgdno

Comment: I'm totally confused. And what do you mean by `it must accept`?

Comment: **1.** `^(.+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|css|png|js|ico))(?:;.+)?$` - matches jpeg,gif,css,png,js and ico with or without `;something` at the end.  **2.** `^(.+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|css|png|js|ico));jsessionid=` matches jpeg,gif,css,png,js and ico only with ;jsessionid= at the end.  **3.** `\.(?:jpe?g|gif|css|png|js|ico)$` - matches jpeg,gif,css,png,js and ico only without anything at the end.

Comment: i need jpeg,gif,css,png,js and ico only WITHOUT ;jsessionid= at the end

Comment: But what else can be after `.png`, `.jpeg`, `.css`...?

Comment: after them everything can be but except ;jsessionBlaBlaBla

Comment: Could you give an example. This is just strange, and `;blabla` is something non-standard to the web.

Comment: Anyway, this is exactly what do you want .................................................................................. `location ~* ^(.+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|css|png|js|ico))(?:$|;(?!jsessionid=)) {`

Comment: bla bla refers to zero, one, or more thing

Comment: I understand what blabla is. =), but `;` is a non-standard method of passing things.

Comment: JSF uses this technic, can i rewrite url getting rid of ;jsessionBlablabla :)

Comment: You can, I already posted here four regular expressions for all possible cases. What's problem? You can write your own, `man pcrepattern`.